# Changing a shape and a colour after a click (GUI, Java)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, java-2d

I'm just learning how GUI works and I wanted to write a code where following happens:

- firstly we see red rectangle
- after a click it changes into a circle in gradient (I picked orange and pink) + the background is black.

The problem is, I don't know how to notify the change when I use `repaint()`, I tried creating the first picture with another method - fail, maybe I lack some knowledge. Currently we get just the second output that doesn't change after the click.

This is the code at the moment I got stuck:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGUI implements ActionListener {
    
    JButton button; 
    JFrame frame;
    
    public void work() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    button = new JButton("Color change");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    
    mojpanel panel = new mojpanel();
        
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
    }   
    }
```

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class mojpanel extends JPanel  {
            
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
g.setColor(Color.black);
    
g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70, Color.orange, 150,150, Color.pink);

((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(gradient);    

g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
}                           
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            SimpleGUI aplGUI = new SimpleGUI();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            mojpanel panel = new mojpanel();
            frame.add(panel);
            aplGUI.work();          
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Painting extends SimpleGUI {

     public void paint(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(Color.red);
         g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
         g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
      }
}
```

Comment: GUIs are not a 'beginner topic', nor is custom painting. This problem could likely be fixed by changing the scope of the relevant (color) attributes and defining methods to set those, for any class that holds a reference to an instance of the class. That should make sense to someone who is ready to make GUIs. If not, go back and study the basics. **Edit:** As an aside, the `Painting` class never seems to be used.

Comment: There is no need for two  `JFrame` instances (one in `Test` and one in  `SimpleGUI`).  Take it step by step: learn how to make a `JFrame` with a `JButton` and a `JPanel`. Later learn how to do custom painting on this `JPanel`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

When you create new classes, you short invest more thought into them. You have two classes which are supposed to be interchangeable, one painting a red rectangle, the other painting a circle with a color gradient, with the ability to switch from the former to the latter.

So when you have one class extending `JPanel` and the other extending `SimpleGUI`, there is no way to exchange one for the other. Further, the names `mojpanel` and `Painting` do not reflect their purposes.

Besides that, you have it backward. Don’t implement an action that calls `repaint()`, followed by an attempt to recognize that `repaint()` has been called, to modify the GUI afterwards. Instead, change the GUI’s state and after the GUI has changed in a way that the visual appearance needs to be updated, call `repaint`. Note that most properties of the Swing components do already trigger an according repaint automatically when you change them.

You may create two classes extending `JComponent` having a custom `paintComponent` method and replace one with the other when the action has been triggered. But there’s a less intrusive way. Let the classes implement `Icon` and set the icon property of a component, e.g. a `JLabel`. This is one of the properties that will trigger the painting automatically:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGUI {
  static class GradientOval implements Icon {
    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
      GradientPaint gradient
          = new GradientPaint(70,70, Color.orange, 150,150, Color.pink);
      ((Graphics2D)g).setPaint(gradient);    
      g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
      return 200;
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
      return 200;
    }
  }
  static class RedRectangle implements Icon {
    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
      return 200;
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
      return 200;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel content = new JLabel(new RedRectangle());
    JButton button = new JButton("Change To Circle");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        content.setIcon(new GradientOval());
      }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

I don’t know which level of Java knowledge you have. The code

```java
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    content.setIcon(new GradientOval());
  }
});
```

creates an instance of an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) implementing `ActionListener`. You can simplify this code using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#lambda-expressions-in-gui-applications):

```java
button.addActionListener(e -> content.setIcon(new GradientOval()));
```

To demonstrate the interaction between component properties and repaints, here an approach using a custom component:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGUI {
  static class DualAppearance extends JComponent {
    private boolean first = true;

    public boolean isFirst() {
      return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(boolean shouldBeFirst) {
      if(shouldBeFirst != first) {
        first = shouldBeFirst;
        repaint();
      }
    }

    public void next() {
      if(first) {
        first = false;
        repaint();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      if(first) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
      }
      else {
        GradientPaint gradient
            = new GradientPaint(70,70, Color.orange, 150,150, Color.pink);
        ((Graphics2D)g).setPaint(gradient);    
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
      return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DualAppearance content = new DualAppearance();
    JButton button = new JButton("Change To Second");
    button.addActionListener(e -> content.next());

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

This `DualAppearance` component follows the usual pattern. When being requested to paint itself, it will always paint itself according to the current state. This may happen multiple times without a state change, due to other reasons, e.g. being requested by the system. When its own state changes and requires a repaint, which only this component can know, it will invoke `repaint`.

You can easily modify this example code to toggle between both appearances by replacing

```java
JButton button = new JButton("Change To Second");
button.addActionListener(e -> content.next());
```

with

```java
JButton button = new JButton("Toggle");
button.addActionListener(e -> content.setFirst(!content.isFirst()));
```